# Replace strings possible with output of PHP file_get_contents?

Tags: php

I'm using PHP to get content from an external website.

I want to know if it's possible to find and replace strings from the output so I can make all links absolute.

I need to convert "/ and '/ to "$url/

If it's possible to do that, I can figure out how to do the rest. I don't know if it's possible though.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simple string replacement, use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php), eg

```
$html = str_replace(array("'/", '"/'), array("'$url/", '"' . $url . '/'), $html);
```

---

If you're after a more robust solution, I'd suggest loading the HTML string into a DOMDocument, loop over all the tags with `href` starting with `/` and change the attribute of each before writing out the HTML.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$anchors = $xpath->query('//*[starts-with(@href, "/")]');

foreach ($anchors as $anchor) {
    $href = $anchor->getAttribute('href');
    $anchor->setAttribute('href', $url . $href);
}
$html = $doc->saveHTML();
```

You'll probably want to do the same for tags with `src` attributes.

Answer (score -1):

You could also use [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), though the DOMDocument parsing is the most robust.

Comment: I just provided some extra info and got down-voted for it? The accepted answer itself mentions str_replace, which is the same thing, just less powerful if you wanted to handle whitespace, etc....